# Не получается сохранить запись в БД Postgres на Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Мне нужно сохранить запись в БД с новым id

```
    id_stat = await request.app.m.stat.get_one(stat_id, connection=connection)         
    if id_stat:                                                                                
        new_stat = {                                                                           
            'name': f"Копия_{id_stat.name}",                                                   
            'company': id_stat.company_id,                                                     
            'analysis': id_stat.analysis_interval,                                             
            'active': False,                                                                                                               
            'debug': id_stat.debug,                                                            
            'items': []                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                          
                                                                                                   
        last_stata = Stat.objects.latest('id').id                                           
        new_stat['id'] = last_stat + 1                                                     
        new_stat.save()
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: &#x27;dict&#x27; object has no attribute &#x27;save&#x27;
```

Прошу помочь найти, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

У вас new_stat - обычный словарь. А не объект Stat.

```
id_stat = await request.app.m.stat.get_one(stat_id, connection=connection)
if id_stat:
    last_stat = Stat.objects.latest('id')
    new_stat = Stat(
        name=f"Копия_{id_stat.name}",
        company=id_stat.company,
        analysis=id_stat.analysis,
        active=False,
        debug=id_stat.debug,
        items=[]
    )
    new_stat.id = last_stat.id + 1
    new_stat.save()
```

Думаю, что так будет работать.